# MySQL Date Calculated Indexes

Tags: mysql

I have a table at least 5 GB and going to be 10 GB in a couple of years. One of the columns is date field which is used in extensively queries. It can be used as Date, Year, Yearmonth and Month for filtering and grouping based on the user's setting in the interface.

```
WHERE yearmonth >= '201504' AND yearmonth <= '201506'  
WHERE year > 2014  
GROUP BY year, month ORDER BY year, month  
SELECT MONTH(date)
```

What is the best method to index on year, month, yearmonth for the queries to have optimum speed without resorting to create these calculated fields in the table itself.

Comment: show schema and sample data

Comment: CREATE TABLE monitor (
  `country` char(3),
  `date` date,
  `year` smallint(4),
  `tvprogramfromtime` time,
  `tvprogramtotime` time,
  `adstarttime` time,
  `timesegment` int(1),
  `bookingagent` int(10),
  `distributor` int(8),
  `sector` int(3),
  `category` int(3),
  `product` int(10),
  `brand` int(8),
  `subbrand` int(8),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: ALTER TABLE monitor
  ADD KEY `country` (`country`),
  ADD KEY `date` (`date`),
  ADD KEY `year` (`year`),
  ADD KEY `category` (`category`),
  ADD KEY `brand` (`brand`),
  ADD KEY `media` (`media`),
  ADD KEY `subbrand` (`subbrand`),
  ADD KEY `product` (`product`),
  ADD KEY `sector` (`sector`)

Comment: that is a partial table right, not the whole thing, you chopped it

Comment: why do you have a date and a year column? What do the other time columns mean?

Comment: as far as what is the best way, it doesn't really matter. You are doing it only once. If I were you, I would simply make sure you do not have de-normalized data, and you have a key

Comment: The original table has triple the fields. It is a table for advertisement on different media. I added year because most of the time the filters are by years. I need yearmonths and I need months and from months I can get quarters. The fields contain the ids of the labels in other tables. I want YEAR(date) and MONTH(date) to execute quickly. In FoxPro I used to index on YEAR(date) and MONTH(date) and the query used to pick them up using Rushmore technology. I am not sure how MySQL does them. I searched a lot to no avail.

Comment: It takes an hour to add or remove a single index. So I cannot afford to play with the data.

Comment: It seems that MySQL does not accept indexes on calculated fields.

Comment: well if you can expand on the data requirements, like write a page or two, perhaps I can craft a zippy fast solution. And not just on how to create an index, but rather how to store your data to begin with. That is what I do and others too. Just point to some doc on the internet. If we simplify things down to 10 words, you get simplified non-useful answers

Comment: Thanks for the offer. If I create the fields and index them then it will do the trick. I have created a summary table which helps 90% of the time. There was a feature in Visual FoxPro to index on calculated fields even if the fields are not there and it was blazingly fast. (Ex. INDEX ON MONTH(date) TAG month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql 5.7 has generated columns feature, and they can be virtual but indexed on:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD COLUMN date_month GENERATED ALWAYS AS MONTH(date) VIRTUAL;
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD INDEX 'index_on_month' (date_month ASC);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, on the servers we have versions 5.0 and 5.6 and cannot change them anytime soon.

Comment: https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/29/generated-virtual-columns-in-mysql-5-7-labs/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that MySQL cannot index on a calculated field.

I got the idea from FoxPro whereby I could do this

```
INDEX ON MONTH(date) TAG month
INDEX ON YEAR(date) TAG year
```

So to solve the problem in MySQL, I have to translate the selected user date filter criteria into formulas on the date field which is indexed.